# JDBC MySQL authentication

Tags: mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector

I am new to JDBC, and I started learning this. I'm trying to establish the connection to my database using the following code.

When I try to run the below code

```java
import java.sql.*;

class DBMS{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb","root","2910");
        
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet re = stmt.executeQuery("select * from mytable");
        while(re.next()){
            System.out.println(re.getInt(1)+" "+re.getString(2)+" "+re.getString(3));
        }
        
        con.close();
    }
}
```

using the command in CMD

```
java -cp .;mysql-connector.jar DBMS
```

where DBMS is the class name.
I get following error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:921)
        .......
        at DBMS.main(dbms.java:7)
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: The solution is right there in the error message: upgrade your MySQL client (in this case, your MySQL Connector/J), see the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly the exception states that you're using the old version of mysql connector to access the latest version of mysql server. Consider upgrading the mysql connector jar. As you didn't mention the mysql server and connector jar version, I would suggest the following things to resolve the issue you're facing:

- Use compatible connector for your mysql server. If you're using
  `mysql server version > 5.6` then you can use MySQL Connector/J 8.0
  (i.e `mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar`)
- Change the following in your code.

  ```
  Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");  
  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useSSL=false","root","2910");
  ```